Default taxonomy view doesn't show fields
I am trying to change the default taxonomy term view to include Fields instead Content (teasers) but I get this error:

Display "Default" uses fields but there are none defined for it or all are excluded.

How to solve that problem?

The main Drupal documentation site covers adding a field to a view:


Navigate to the edit screen for your view (for example, admin/structure/views/MY_VIEW_NAME/edit).
In the Fields section, click Add. The Add Fields dialog box is displayed.
In the For field, select one of the following options:
All Displays The field will be added to all of the displays in the current view.
This Page Override The field will only be added to the current display.
From the list, select one or more fields. Tip: You can filter the list by typing in the Search box or by selecting 1. from the Type
dropdown list.
Click Apply. The Configure Field dialog box displays.
Optional step: Enable the Create a Label option and enter the text in the Label field.
Enable or disable the Exclude From Display option. This allows you to hide the field if it is only used for 1. configuration purposes
such as specifying how the view output is grouped.
Click Apply. If you selected more than one field, The Configure Field dialog box for the next field will be displayed and you must
repeat steps 6 through 8.


