How to create a view that shows only node titles and nothing else?
Sometimes, a view of teasers or full contents or anything like these data structures is just too much for me and I just want to show node titles (linking to each node).
How to create a view that shows only node titles and nothing else?


Go to /admin/structure/views/add.
Set a view name.
By default, View settings will be show Content.  Modify this for the entities you want to show.
Save the view by pressing Save and edit.

The created view will have Fields set for the Format, and the default field will be Content: Title.
This seems to be what you want, and it is the default behavior of Views.
If you don't want the title to link to the content, click Content: Title under Fields and then uncheck Link to the Content.

I try to change the default taxonomy term view to include Fields instead Content (teasers) but I get the error Display "Default" uses fields but there are none defined for it or all are excluded.. Basically all I want is just that the default taxonomy term view will shows fields (node titles) instead of teasers or full contents and I have asked a question about it here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/320432/how-to-make-the-taxonomy-term-view-to-show-only-node-titles-without-a-teaser-co

@lahiente It seems like you need to read the documentation or some tutorials on Views.  As the message says, you need to define a field, which you do by clicking the add button for fields and then choosing title.

See, for example, the excellent user guide from Drupalize.me: https://drupalize.me/guide/drupal-user-guide

I missed that cell Fields just under the cell Format. Oh, I came out so silly here. I wonder why the developers of the Views module made a separate cell for Fields instead just making its options part of the Format cell but that's for another discussion I guess. Thanks a bunch.
